# JSON Uncaught Type Error

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the instagram API and if a caption doesnt exist or doesnt have text it doesnt include the node at all. So I included a check to see if caption exists which works, but if caption exists and the child node text does not, then I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null`.

This is my code:

```
for (p in pictures) {
  if (pictures[p].hasOwnProperty('caption')) {
    if (pictures[p].caption.text != null) {
      captionString = pictures[p].caption.text;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if the caption is null, there is no caption ? (but a caption property is here to inform you that there is no caption available), so you should add a captionString only if the caption property is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `caption` property exists, but it seems to be `null` for some cases, and when you evaluate `(null).text`, you are getting the error detailed in your question.

Add `pictures[p].caption &&` to evaluate for `caption` in your inner `if`.

This should work for you (note that I also merge your two `if`s and I did all evaluations in only one `if`):

```
for(p in pictures) {
  if (pictures[p].hasOwnProperty('caption') && pictures[p].caption && pictures[p].caption.text != null) {
    captionString = pictures[p].caption.text;
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to have worked. Do you know why this works but not the way I did it? Why do I get an error on the nested if statement check and not on this?

Comment: Note that I did a little refactor and I merge your 2 "ifs", the point is that I add an evaluation for `pictures[p].caption`, if this is `null`, it will return false for the if statement

Answer (score 0):

you could just try :

```
if(pictures[p].caption != null){
     captionString = pictures[p].caption.text;
}
```

instead of

```
if(pictures[p].hasOwnProperty('caption')){
     if(pictures[p].caption.text != null){
          captionString = pictures[p].caption.text;
     }
}
```

Because the caption property is always here, but may be null if not available

Comment: I did, but there can be a caption and no caption text. Not sure why but it happens. I checked the JSON output